# How do I respond to a touch *down* event in the UITabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'd like to begin animating a `UITabBarItem` when the user touches *down* on the tab. However, `UITabBarDelegate` only provides a `didSelect` method. What's the best way of detecting a `UIControlEvents.touchDown` event in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subclass `UITabBar` and override `hitTest:withEvent:`

Here's an example of a subclass that slightly scales down the image upon touch-down, then restores it upon touch-up-inside

```
@interface TRCTabBar : UITabBar

@end


@implementation TRCTabBar

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:UIControl.class]) {
        CGFloat scale = 0.90;
        CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.14 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            view.transform = t;
        } completion:nil];
    }
    return view;
}

// used as a signal to restore the image back to its original state
- (void)setSelectedItem:(UITabBarItem *)selectedItem {
    [super setSelectedItem:selectedItem];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(view.transform)) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Some notes:

1. Unlike the touch-down event that's accessed via `hitTest:withEvent:`, the touch-up-inside event isn't accessed directly; Simply override `setSelectedItem:` to have a chance to perform some actions when the user lifts their finger.
2. There's no way to monitor a touch-up-**outside** (or any other cancellation event, for this matter). So if a user taps, then drags outside, then lifts their finger, the image remains scaled down until next `setSelectedItem:` is called.
3. If you use animations (like in my provided example code), you must use the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option. Otherwise `setSelectedItem:` isn't always called.
4. You only want to pick up touches from the `UITabBarButton` class (that's the control that responds to the touch-down event). A user may also accidentally touch the `UITabBar` itself, and you should ignore this touch. `UITabBarButton` is an internal UIKit class, but it's a subclass of `UIControl`. Use that to filter out all other ignored `UIView`s (like the `UITabBar` itself).
5. Obviously, make sure to set your `UITabBar`'s class (in Interface Builder or programatically) as your custom class.